# What is the name of the z axis?

Tags: graphing-functions

If *x* is the horizontal axis and *y* is the vertical axis, then what do you call the *z* axis that is perpendicular to both *x* and *y*? The one that comes directly toward and away from you.

In other words,

width = horizontal

height = vertical

depth = ?

---

Please add any tags that fit.

Comment: As shocking asw it may sound, it is usually called "the $z$ - axis" ... sometimes it is also called "the vertical axis", but this depends on the point of view.

Comment: The terms "horizontal" and "vertical" are used for the $xy$ plane. In 3D, these terms don't fit nicely anymore. In your case, the positive z-axis comes towards you (by the preferred Right Hand Rule), but back in High school, we learned to draw the y-axis horizontal, the z-axis vertical and the x-axis slanted towards us...

Answer (score 1):

The z-axis, is also sometimes known as.... the z-axis.

If you are drawing the axes as they are typically taught in school, the z-axis becomes the "height", the y-axis is "width" and I guess you could say that the x-axis becomes "depth" or "length"

Comment: This is what I do - length, width and height.

Comment: Maybe there just isn't a name for it

Answer (score 1):

It's called the Applical axis as it is used for many different applications, as in computer engineering the Applical axis is used as intensity when plotting two wave forms on a Cartesian plane and in physics it's used as depth.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).